# Sign function in Scheme?

Tags: function, scheme, racket, sign

Does Scheme have a sign function? I could not find any information about that.

I define a sign function as a function which produces -1 when x<0, 0 when x=0 and 1 when x>0.

Comment: Well, if there isn't any, it should be "trivial" to write one: 0 if x is 0, x / abs(x) otherwise

Comment: Scheme philosophy is building from base up; you don't get so many libraries as in, say, CLOS, but you can pretty much make anything you want, mold the language in the way you like. As @fge says - if your Scheme doesn't have the sign function, it's trivial to make one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use the built-in [`sgn`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmath..rkt%29._sgn%29%29) procedure:

```
(sgn -10)
=> -1
(sgn 10)
=> 1
(sgn 0)
=> 0
```

In case you're wondering how to implement it...

```
(define (sign n)
  (cond ((negative? n) -1)
        ((positive? n)  1)
        (else 0)))
```